# Action Script Project : Tutorials for Action Script Project using flex sdk

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to work on Action Script project. I need to generate a swiff file by creating an action script project using flex sdk . I dont know how to start this thing. I have installed flex 4.5.1 and I know how to create flex project. Can u please suggest me some tutorials for working with action script project using flex sdk.

Thanks.....

Comment: Not a real question as this is subjective.  Please do your research first and come back with a more precise question.

Comment: Hi prabhu M, I would suggest you to buy a book that will lead you through the learning process if Flex. Moreover, AS3 knowlege is essential. You can start with: Getting Started with Flex 4 - Oreilly and Flex 4 Cookbook - Oreilly. Both are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, there are lots of free tutorials in the internet, for example on youtube. you wouldn't be able to really learn actionscript but you will understand basics, so learning will be much easier. [here, take a look](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=flash%20builder%204.5%20tutorial&aq=3&oq=flash%20builder). also, i can strongly recommend [lynda](http://www.lynda.com/search?q=flash%20builder&x=0&y=0)'s training courses -- yes, you have to pay for them, but they've got free trial membership. also, take a look at google, you know... you don't expect someone actually to teach you personally, don't you?...